# Is it possible to print 1,2,3......n using SYS_REFCURSOR in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to oracle and learned collection and cursor today and I have some curosity about SYS_REFCURSOR.Since,SYS_REFCURSOR can hold multiple data,I wanted to send a number to the function and print the data as:
suppose if i send n=5 then my output will be like,

```
-------
i     |
-------
 1    |
  2   |
  3   |
  4   |
   5  |
```

And if I send n=10 then,

```
-------
i     |
-------
 1    |
  2   |
  3   |
  4   |
   5  |
  6   |
   7  |
   8  |
   9  |
  10  |
```

I did it with collection,but is it possible to do it with SYS_REFCURSOR? I tried like this but output is not coming:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OT.NATURAL_NUMB(
data1 NUMBER
)
return SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
A_B SYS_REFCURSOR; 
BEGIN
open A_B 
FOR i in 1 .. data1
loop
A_B :=i;
END LOOP;
RETURN A_B;
END;
/
```

What is the mistake here in my code or is there any other solution?

Comment: Is the indentation only by mistake or it is intentional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to print numbers from 1 till that particular number passed from the parameter, You can use below function -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OT.NATURAL_NUMB(data1 NUMBER)
return SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
A_B SYS_REFCURSOR; 
BEGIN
    open A_B FOR
         SELECT ROWNUM
         FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= data1
    RETURN A_B;
END;
/
```